# If statements with radio buttons not assigning variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, if-statement, radio-button

I'm trying to learn about form building. I have form in which I would like to assign the value of certain variables to certain form fields, based on which radio button is selected. But my code is always defaulting to the first radio choice, no matter which one I select.

I've tried to chain 'if' conditions, if/else conditions and alter variable names, but it doesn't make a difference.

I've also found that the code doesn't work in JSfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/GEZPU/1/), but I'm not sure why it says the function is not defined?.

HTML

```
    Input 1
<select id="box0">
    <option>Tampa</option>
    <option>Phoenix</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Input 2
<select id="box1">
    <option>Bucs</option>
    <option>Cards</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>If option radios
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="box2" name="football" value="No Data">No Data
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="box3" name="football" value="No Playoffs">No Playoffs
<br>Games to go?
<input id="box4" size="10">Superbowl location?
<input id="box5" size="10">
<br>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="box6" name="football" value="Yes Playoffs">Made Playoffs
<br>Superbowl location?
<input id="box7" size="10">
<p>
    <input value="Write summary" onclick="writetext()" type="button">
    <br>
    <form>
        <textarea rows="35" cols="45" placeholder="Template" id="output"></textarea>
    </form>
    <br>
</p>
```

Code

```
    function writetext() {
    var mytext = document.getElementById('output');
    var captext = "";
    // Checklist variables
    var box_0 = $("#box0").val();
    var box_1 = $("#box1").val();
    captext += box_0 + "\n - " + box_1 + "\n ";

    if ($('#box2').prop("checked ", true)) {
        var box_margin = $("#box2").val();
        captext += "\nMargins: \n - " + box_margin + "\n ";
    }
    if ($('#box3').prop("checked ", true)) {
        var box_margin2 = $("#box3").val();
        var box_margin_dist = $("#box4").val();
        var box_margin_site = $("#box5").val();
        captext += "\nMargins: \n - " + box_margin2 + "\n - Dist: " + box_margin_dist + "\n - margin " + box_margin_site + "\n ";
    }
    if ($('#box6').prop("checked ", true)) {
        var box_margin3 = $("#box6 ").val();
        var box_margin_site3 = $("#box7 ").val();
        captext += "\nMargins: \n - " + box_margin3 + "\n - (Specify margin)" + box_margin_site3 + "\n ";
    }

    mytext.value = captext;
}
```

Comment: You're using jQuery anyway, use it for everything. Your checked checks were wrong. This should do what you wanted, notice the changes to how the button fires. http://jsfiddle.net/T9HWD/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($('#box2').prop("checked ", true)) {
```

**is always true.**. I think you are trying to compare if it is set to true or false.

Supposed to be

```
if ($('#box2').prop("checked ")) {
```

It is always a good idea to avoid attaching events inline. Attach the events using javascript

Also you can simply use `is(':checked')` method to check if the radio is checked or not.

I observed that you are, using the same jQuery object in multiple places. It would be better to cache them in such instances as it will improve the performance.

And the same code can be  refactored a bit ..

**UPDATE**

```
$('#write').click(write);

function write() {
    var mytext = document.getElementById('output'),
        captext = "",
        // box elements
        $box_0 = $('#box0'),
        $box_1 = $('#box1'),
        $box_2 = $('#box2'),
        $box_3 = $('#box3'),
        $box_4 = $('#box4'),
        $box_5 = $('#box5'),
        $box_6 = $('#box6'),
        $box_7 = $('#box7'),
        // Checklist variables
        box_0 = $box_0.val();
    box_1 = $box_1.val();

    captext += box_0 + "\n - " + box_1 + "\n ";
    // All the radios have the same name.
    // So only 1 radio will be checked at any point of time
    // This would give you the radio that is checked
    var $radio = $('input[type=radio][name=football]:checked');

    if ($radio.length) {
        captext += "\nMargins: \n - " + $radio.val() + "\n ";

        if ($radio.is($box_3)) {
            captext += "\n - Dist: " + $box_4.val() + "\n - margin " + $box_5.val() + "\n ";
        } else if ($radio.is($box_6)) {
            captext += "\n - (Specify margin)" + $box_7.val() + "\n ";
        }
    }
    mytext.value = captext;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GEZPU/7/)**

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that the ', true' bit rendered it always true, I thought it checked whether the arguement was true. I changed it and it worked just like I wanted. On a separate note, is it better to chain multiple 'if's or chain 'if/else's together?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at http://api.jquery.com/prop/ you'll notice that .prop("checked") returns true or false while .prop("checked", true) assigned the value 'true' to the property "checked".  Try switching those out and see what happens.